# Python Invalid type encountered in the arguments

Tags: python, django

How to correctly turn a shapefile into MultiPolygon? I get the following error when trying to turn a shapefile into a MultiPolygon...

```
.401 395951.4, 238087.5 395958.5, 238086.5 395963, 238086.3 395968.2, 238087.3 395973, 238090.7 395980.6, 238094.2 395989.2, 238101 395993.2, 238107.7 395994.1, 238114 395993.8, 238121.3 395992.6, 238131.6 395988.6, 238146.9 395978.2, 238184.401 395960.9, 238196.6 395958.4, 238203.1 395956.801, 238214.599 395953.4)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geo.py", line 25, in <module>
    Multi = MultiPolygon([pol['geometry'] for pol in fiona.open(file)])
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py", line 38, in __init__
    self._check_allowed(init_geoms)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/mutable_list.py", line 261, in _check_allowed
    raise TypeError('Invalid type encountered in the arguments.')
file = 'NUTS1_DEC_2008_EW_BFE.shp'
```

Code that generates error:

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
c = fiona.open(file)
pol = c.next()
geom = shape(pol['geometry'])

Multi = MultiPolygon([pol['geometry'] for pol in fiona.open(file)])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MultiPolygon](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py#L131) objects inherits from [GeometryCollection](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py#L19).
Looking `GeometryCollection.__ini__()` method you can see there is a call to `self._check_allowed()` method. `self._check_allowed()` comes from [GEOSGeometry](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py#L26) and [ListMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geos/mutable_list.py#L18) class, that is where `_check_allowed()` id [defined](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geos/mutable_list.py#L250):

```
...
def _check_allowed(self, items):
    if hasattr(self, '_allowed'):
        if False in [isinstance(val, self._allowed) for val in items]:
            raise TypeError('Invalid type encountered in the arguments.')
...
```

As you can see, the above method check if each item is instance of any following types:

```
Point, LineString, LinearRing, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon
```

And it can be found here, in `django/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py`, line [#108](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py#L108):

```
# Setting the allowed types here since GeometryCollection is defined before
# its subclasses.
GeometryCollection._allowed = (Point, LineString, LinearRing, Polygon, 
                                MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon)
```

That said, It's probably `fiona.open()` doesn't return any valid allowed types.
I'm not a GeoDjango expert, but it strikes me using `django.contrib.gis.utils.LayerMapping` does the trick.
Reading the tutoria from GeoDjango docs seems fairly easy: [GeoDjango Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geodjango-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to `.read()` on the file, right?

```
Multi = MultiPolygon([pol['geometry'] for pol in fiona.open(file).read()])
```

Comment: I don't think so, This works to a point then generates the error towards the end: ``for pol in fiona.open(file):``

Comment: maybe there is an empty line or a null char?

Answer (score 0):

This solves a problem for me:

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource

In [2]: from django.contrib.gis.geos import MultiPolygon

In [3]: polygon = """
   ...: {
   ...:   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   ...:   "features": [
   ...:     {
   ...:       "type": "Feature",
   ...:       "properties": {},
   ...:       "geometry": {
   ...:         "type": "Polygon",
   ...:         "coordinates": [
   ...:           [
   ...:             [
   ...:               28.652343749999996,
   ...:               48.748945343432936
   ...:             ],
   ...:             [
   ...:               33.75,
   ...:               48.748945343432936
   ...:             ],
   ...:             [
   ...:               33.75,
   ...:               50.3454604086048
   ...:             ],
   ...:             [
   ...:               28.652343749999996,
   ...:               50.3454604086048
   ...:             ],
   ...:             [
   ...:               28.652343749999996,
   ...:               48.748945343432936
   ...:             ]
   ...:           ]
   ...:         ]
   ...:       }
   ...:     }
   ...:   ]
   ...: }
   ...: """

In [4]: ds = DataSource(polygon)

In [5]: layer = ds[0]

In [6]: feature = next((f for f in layer))

In [7]: feature
Out[7]: <django.contrib.gis.gdal.feature.Feature at 0x7f4bdbbdc970>

In [8]: feature.geom
Out[8]: <django.contrib.gis.gdal.geometries.Polygon at 0x7f4bdbdd0070>

In [9]: MultiPolygon([feature.geom.geos])
Out[9]: <MultiPolygon object at 0x7f4bdbf0b090>
```